# Removing ending letter from number, and ordering

Tags: sql

I have a column in a table that contains seat numbers that look like this: 10D, 4E, 12A..etc
I am trying to take off the ending letters, and order them by ascending order. My code below takes off the ending letter, but it doesn't order them correct.
It orders them like this:
10
12
13
3
4
7
8

```
    select distinct rtrim(col_name(col_name, 1, LENGTH(col_name) - 1)) as "Row" from table
    order by rtrim(substr(col_name, 1, LENGTH(col_name) - 1));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to cast to a numeric type to get numerical ordering. For example

```
order by cast(rtrim(substr(col_name, 1, LENGTH(col_name) - 1)) as int);
```

Assuming your RDBMS supports cast to `int`. If MySQL you could use `UNSIGNED` in place of `int`

Comment: +1 : *As otherwise you are ordering alpha-numerically on a string type.